# Geomesa: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: gis, geomesa

Trying to ingest shapefiles with over 600 columns in Geomesa I get the following error.

```
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter.writeFeature(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:56)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter.writeFeature$(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:46)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter$TableFeatureWriter.writeFeature(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:151)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter$GeoMesaAppendFeatureWriter.write(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:239)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter$GeoMesaAppendFeatureWriter.write$(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:235)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter$$anon$3.write(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:111)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.FeatureUtils$.write(FeatureUtils.scala:147)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$8(LocalConverterIngest.scala:181)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$8$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:179)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:575)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:573)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$FlatMapCloseableIterator.foreach(CloseableIterator.scala:132)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$7(LocalConverterIngest.scala:179)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$7$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:173)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.CloseablePool$CommonsPoolPool.borrow(CloseablePool.scala:68)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$6(LocalConverterIngest.scala:173)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$6$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:172)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.package$WithClose$.apply(package.scala:64)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4(LocalConverterIngest.scala:172)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:575)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:573)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$CloseableSingleIterator.foreach(CloseableIterator.scala:85)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.package$WithClose$.apply(package.scala:64)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.CloseablePool$CommonsPoolPool.borrow(CloseablePool.scala:68)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.run(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2136 out of bounds for length 1024
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeByte(Output.java:226)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.serialization.WkbSerialization.serializeWkb(WkbSerialization.scala:44)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.serialization.WkbSerialization.serializeWkb$(WkbSerialization.scala:42)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.serialization.KryoGeometrySerialization$.serializeWkb(KryoGeometrySerialization.scala:14)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.impl.KryoFeatureSerialization$KryoGeometryWkbWriter$.apply(KryoFeatureSerialization.scala:229)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.impl.KryoFeatureSerialization.writeFeature(KryoFeatureSerialization.scala:71)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.impl.KryoFeatureSerialization.serialize(KryoFeatureSerialization.scala:43)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.impl.KryoFeatureSerialization.serialize$(KryoFeatureSerialization.scala:41)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.features.kryo.KryoFeatureSerializer$MutableActiveSerializer.serialize(KryoFeatureSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.api.WritableFeature$FeatureLevelWritableFeature.$anonfun$values$2(WritableFeature.scala:153)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.api.package$KeyValue.value$lzycompute(package.scala:183)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.api.package$KeyValue.value(package.scala:183)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloIndexAdapter$AccumuloIndexWriter.$anonfun$write$1(AccumuloIndexAdapter.scala:397)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloIndexAdapter$AccumuloIndexWriter.$anonfun$write$1$adapted(AccumuloIndexAdapter.scala:396)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.foreach(Vector.scala:1895)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloIndexAdapter$AccumuloIndexWriter.write(AccumuloIndexAdapter.scala:396)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.api.IndexAdapter$BaseIndexWriter.write(IndexAdapter.scala:153)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter.writeFeature(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:50)
        ... 34 more
```

The error occurs on both older and newer versions of Geomesa. I have tried installing the latest versions of some key libraries, such as GeoTools and Kryo, but the problem persists.

Could it make sense to change the way the data is serialized? If so, can it be done without recompiling the code?

Comment: Here is an example shapefile that throws the error https://files.fm/u/raeahqpku

Comment: GeoTools opens that file with no issues

Comment: @IanTurton The error is triggered when you try to ingest it with the command geomesa-accumulo ingest --force -i accumulo -z zookeeper -u username -p myPassword -c myCatalog -f myFeature  /path/to/shapefile

Comment: I've created a ticket to track the issue here: https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-3289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a [bug](https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-3289) in GeoMesa affecting schemas with > 479 attributes. It has been [fixed](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/commit/d3883a6bcec261956e9b2e88fa6838a2e9ffd358) in `main`, and will be available in the next release (4.1.0). In the meantime, you can [build from source](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/tree/main#building-from-source) if you need the fix immediately.